# NullPointerException when printing array of objects

Tags: java

I have this lab to do for college and I'm getting a `java.lang.NullPointerException` and I cant figure out the problem with my code.

```
package Lab2Revision;

public class Manager extends Employee {

    private String deptName;
    private Employee[] staff;
    private int employeeCount = 0;

    public Manager(int empid, String name, String ssn, double salary, String deptName)
    {
        super(empid, name, ssn, salary);
        this.deptName = deptName;
        staff = new Employee[20];
    }

    public String getDeptName(){
        return deptName;
    }

    public int findEmployee(Employee e)
    {
        int a =0;
        for(int i = 0; i < staff.length; i++)
        {
            if(e == staff[i])
            {
                a = -1;
            }
            else
            {
                a = i;
            }
        }
        return a;
    }

    public boolean addEmployee(Employee e)
    {
        boolean a = true;

            if(findEmployee(e) != -1)
            {
                staff[employeeCount] = e;
                employeeCount++;
                a = true;
                System.out.println(staff[employeeCount]);
            }
            else
            {
                a = false;
            }

        return a;
    }

    public boolean removeEmployee(Employee e)
    {
        boolean a = false;
        Employee [] tempStaff = null;
        int tempCount = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < staff.length; i++)
        {
            if(staff[i].getEmpid() != e.getEmpid())
            {
                tempStaff[tempCount] = staff[i];
                tempCount++;
            }
            else
            {
                a = true;
            }
        }
        staff = tempStaff;
        employeeCount = tempCount;
        return a;
    }

    public String printStaffDetails()
    {
        String a = "Staff of " + getName() + "\n";

        for(int i = 0; i < staff.length; i++)
        {
        a += "Name: " + staff[i].getName() + " Employee id:  "  + staff[i].getEmpid() + "\n" ;
        }
        return a;
    }
    public String toString(){
        return super.toString() + "Department: \t " + deptName + "\n";
    }
}
```

And this is my test:

```
package Lab2Revision;

public class TestEmployee {

    public static void main(String [] aargs){

        Engineer e1 = new Engineer(101, "Jane Smith", "012-34-5678", 120345.27,"");
        Admin  e2 = new Admin(304, "Bill Munroe", "108-23-6509", 75002.34,"");
        Manager e3 = new Manager(207, "Barbara Johnson",  "054-12-2367", 109501.36, "US Marketing");
        Director  e4 = new Director(12, "Susan Wheeler", "099-45-2340", 120567.36, "Global Marketing", 1000000.0);
        Engineer e5 = new Engineer(120, "Bill Lecomte", "045-89-1010", 110450.34,"");

        System.out.println(e1);
        System.out.println(e5);
        System.out.println(e2);
        System.out.println(e3);
        System.out.println(e4);

        e3.addEmployee(e1);
        e3.addEmployee(e2);
        e3.addEmployee(e5);

        /*if(e3.addEmployee(e1) == true)
        {
            System.out.println("Success: added admin");
        }

        if(e3.addEmployee(e2) == true)
        {
            System.out.println("Success: added eng1");
        }

        if(e3.addEmployee(e5) == true)
        {
            System.out.println("Success: added eng2");
        }
        */

        e3.raiseSalary(10000);

        System.out.println(e3.printStaffDetails());;  
    }
}
```

The problem is in the `addEmployee()` method, I only want to solve this problem, if you see other problems that do not arise from this error, (unless its just better coding practices) please do not inform me, I will come to it myself and figure it out.

The line `staff[employeeCount] = e;` in the `addEmployee()` method doesn't seem to be adding the Employee to the staff array, giving me null values and causing the error.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Could you please post the error you get (with the line and everything)?

Comment: row where it happens could help..

Comment: You say not to inform you of any other errors, but there are serious problems that affect the method you're trying to fix. For example, `findEmployee` does not work at all. The conditions seem to be swapped and you reset the result on every iteration.

Comment: The exact error is:

    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at Lab2Revision.Manager.printStaffDetails(Manager.java:87)
 at Lab2Revision.TestEmployee.main(TestEmployee.java:44)

Comment: OK, which line of Manager is line 87? That's where some object reference is null that shouldn't be. Figure out which, figure out why, fix it.

Comment: Well, that particular problem is quite straight forward. In your array of size 20, there's no guaranteed every element is an initialized employee. Check if `staff[i] != null` before trying to print.

Comment: @Zong Zheng Li

findEmployee() seems fine to me,could you Elaborate on what you think is wrong with it?

Comment: @ keshlam
Line 87
a += "Name: " + staff[i].getName() + " Employee id:  "  + staff[i].getEmpid() + "\n" ;

Comment: I suggest you take a careful look at `findEmployee` then. Use a debugger, put some print statements, or walk through a test case by hand.

Comment: @Zong Zheng Li 

I have already done your suggestion as my first port of call and I get a print out of null 3 times

Comment: I will restate that the method has serious problems that would be obvious from some basic testing. If you don't believe me, see the output (under stdout at the bottom) of a [quick test I put together](http://ideone.com/gCGG5d).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The instance variable `staff` is initialized to length 20.  You're iterating from 0 to 19 in your `printStaffDetails` method, regardless of how many employees have been actually added.  You should use `employeeCount` as the loop's upper bound.

As Zong Zheng points out, if you add employees after removing some, this will break again.  The obvious workaround is to loop all of them and check for `null`-ness, or use a sane data structure like a `List`.

Comment: I don't think you can assume non-null elements are adjacent given his current implementation of `removeEmployee` (which doesn't look like it works at all, but you know what I mean).

Comment: We are doing this to show us why we use ArrayList and not array's

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Whoops, I obviously posted an answer without looking at the code more closely.

addEmployee() works (sortof, there's still a problem)

The staff[] array is initialized of size 20, but in your test method you only added 3 employees.
The loop in printStaffDetails() will loop through all 20 elements, of which only 3 is non-null. So calling staff[i].getName() will throw nullPointer.

Comment: Actually, `findEmployee` doesn't return -1 most of the time.

Comment: The if condition in addEmployee() works, when I debug it runs the line
    staff[employeeCount] = e;

My print out from 
    System.out.println(staff[employeeCount]);

is

null
null
null